# Ubuntu forgets mouse settings (lefthanded)

Tags: gnome, mouse, settings

I work on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LT
Gnome 3.36.3

As I'm left-handed I changed the mouse settings:
Primary Button = Right.

So far, this worked fine.

Since yesterday I confronted with a weird effect. After logon, these settings seem to have no effect.

When I check the settings they are as indicated, but seem to take no effect. Only when I put the seetings to
Primary Button = left
and then back to
Primary Button = Right

this start to work correctly.

it's the same effect as descibed in
[Primary button goes back to default on external mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283389/primary-button-goes-back-to-default-on-external-mouse)

Nevertheless the solution marked there does not work for me. I can execute the command direct in terminal or as shellscript - I performs with no error, but has no effect on stated problem.

Still I can't accept this nuissance. How the I correct this? Best would be to make the mouse settings permanent/sticky. Even if the script would work, it's a nogo to have to reset correct settings value 50-100 times during a day of work.

Comment: Look Answers on this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283389/primary-button-goes-back-to-default-on-external-mouse

Answer (score 0):

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse left-handed true`

On 20.04, the effect is immediate and persists through reboots....

I also run MATE 20.04:
on MATE `gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-mouse left-handed true`

*(man this was so annoying to test!!! so sorry, to you folks that have to live with this bodily malfunction)*